# How to validate a text field on value changed?

Tags: forms, flutter, dart

How to autovalidate a text form field when its value changes?

i tried

```dart
bool _autoValidate = false;
```

```dart
TextFormField(
                autovalidate: _autoValidate ,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _autoValidate = true;
                  });
                },
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.length < 5) {
                    return 'False';
                  } else {
                    return 'True';
                  }
                },
              ),
```

But not working, `TextFormField` still doesn't show errors on validation.

I need a way to turn on the validation on text changed.

Comment: I checked your code. It is giving me true after i enter 5 digits

Comment: stop your app and run it again. Don't hot reload it

Comment: try to stop running your app and run flutter clean in cmd/terminal

Comment: @Maz341 it's gives true but still doesn't show errors!! there no red border or the texthint of error

Comment: @Uni I did flutter clean and still no erros shows, even the _autoValidate  var is true, the validation still not working

Comment: your validator should return null on valid state and not null for invalid state

Comment: @MBN I tried it before I did this code to see if the validation will works anyway, but still not working, i need it show the error after value changed

Comment: did you use the form in the parent widgets? can you post full code?

Comment: @MBN yes I do 
Form(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              imagePickerWidget(context),
              TextFormField....

Comment: @MBN I removed it and still not working

Comment: i tried your code and it's ok! maybe another problem occurs elsewhere

Comment: @MBN what? the validation works?! the validation errors is show up?!

Comment: https://gifyu.com/image/6nAP

Comment: @MBN But the autovalidate was true from the beginning and giving you the validation error, I need it false first then become true on text changes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222440/discussion-between-mbn-and-abdallah-el-rashedy).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Flutter has now an API to validate a form field only when the content changes. You just need to use the `autovalidateMode` parameter and set it to `AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction`.

The following text field will only validate when the user changes its content:

```dart
    class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: Center(
            child: TextFormField(
              autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

See [AutovalidateMode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutovalidateMode-class.html) docs for more options in when to validate.

This API is now available on the latest stable channel. Let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: it's needs import or something?

Comment: The named parameter 'autovalidateMode' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'autovalidateMode'.

Comment: flutter --version
Flutter 1.20.4 • channel stable

Comment: You need to upgrade to the latest stable channel, it is now 1.22.X.

Just run: flutter upgrade

Comment: I got `'vsync != null': is not true.` error when I removed it!

Comment: This is just the analyzer complaining for the new required keyword. Your code can still run without problems.

Comment: it's works but I got errors in an animated widget after upgrade

Comment: nope, the errors is fixed now after restart the vs code many times

Comment: Great solution, thanks