# How to validate the TextFormField as we type in the input in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-textformfield

I have created a login screen with textformfield for email id and password using flutter. Also, I have added the validation to check these fields. The code is as below;

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
    home: HomePage(),
    theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
    ),
    );
}
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
var _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
var isLoading = false;

void _submit() {
    final isValid = _formKey.currentState.validate();
    if (!isValid) {
    return;
    }
    _formKey.currentState.save();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Form Validation"),
        leading: Icon(Icons.filter_vintage),
    ),
    //body
    body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        //form
        child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
            Text(
                "Form-Validation In Flutter ",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            //styling
            SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
            ),
            TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'E-Mail'),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                //Validator
                },
                validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty ||
                    !RegExp(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+")
                        .hasMatch(value)) {
                    return 'Enter a valid email!';
                }
                return null;
                },
            ),
            //box styling
            SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
            ),
            //text input
            TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                onFieldSubmitted: (value) {},
                obscureText: true,
                validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Enter a valid password!';
                }
                return null;
                },
            ),
            SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                vertical: 10.0,
                horizontal: 15.0,
                ),
                child: Text(
                "Submit",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 24.0,
                ),
                ),
                onPressed: () => _submit(),
            )
            ],
        ),
        ),
    ),
    );
}
}
```

The issue I am facing is, I want to validate the fields as soon as the user starts typing the input(dynamically) rather than clicking on the submit button to wait for the validation to happen. I did a lot of research yet could not find a solution. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: validate using``onChanged`` callback !! https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes

Comment: You can do it by checking if the ``_formKey`` is empty in the login button.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate a text field on value changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64182372/how-to-validate-a-text-field-on-value-changed)

Answer (score 2):

May be this can help someone. Inside the **TextFormField** use this line of code:

```
 autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction
```

Comment: ``autovalidateMode`` is for something else If I am not wrong. Please check.

Comment: See this answer on [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64182730/16592270)

Answer (score 0):

**Flutter Form Validation with TextFormField**

Here's an alternative implementation of the _TextSubmitWidgetState that uses a Form:

```
class _TextSubmitWidgetState extends State<TextSubmitForm> {
  // declare a GlobalKey
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  // declare a variable to keep track of the input text
  String _name = '';

  void _submit() {
    // validate all the form fields
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      // on success, notify the parent widget
      widget.onSubmit(_name);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // build a Form widget using the _formKey created above.
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Enter your name',
            ),
            // use the validator to return an error string (or null) based on the input text
            validator: (text) {
              if (text == null || text.isEmpty) {
                return 'Can\'t be empty';
              }
              if (text.length < 4) {
                return 'Too short';
              }
              return null;
            },
            // update the state variable when the text changes
            onChanged: (text) => setState(() => _name = text),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            // only enable the button if the text is not empty
            onPressed: _name.isNotEmpty ? _submit : null,
            child: Text(
              'Submit',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

source : https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-text-field-form-validation/

Answer (score 0):

use autovalidateMode in your Form widget

```
Form(
        key: _formKey,
        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
        child: FormUI(),
    ),
```